# How to calculate the electrical conductivity of an insulating dielectric?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, dielectric

So I am told that the dispersion relation for an EM wave in a conducting medium is:
$$k^2 = \mu_0 \epsilon \omega^2 + i\omega \mu_0 \sigma_n$$

where $k$ is the wavevector, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $\sigma_n$ is the electrical conductivity.
So my questions says if EM waves of frequency $5 \times 10^14 \ Hz$ are fired into a insulating dielectric 20km thick then the amplitude of the wave has been reduced in amplitude by only one part in $10^{10}$. Then I am asked to calculate the conductivity of this gas cloud. Now I know that for highly conducting materials, I can use the "skin depth" which is defines as:
$$\delta = (\frac{2}{w \mu_0\sigma_n})^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
But in this case the conductor is very poor, so this definition cannot be used (I assume), so can I calculate an approximate value for the electrical conductivity of this material?